# How do I put an escape character (NOT "escaped" character) in a Ruby regex?

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to parse a text file that has ANSI color sequences in it, e.g.

```
\e[0;37m
```

How can I build a regex to match this in Ruby?

Comment: Can't you use `\e`? See http://docs.huihoo.com/ruby/ruby-man-1.4/syntax.html#string

Comment: Aww geez.  That's what I had at first but it didn't seem like it was working.  I figured out the issue after a bit of more experimentation: the regex was working but the output was coming from the iterator that held the original raw value.  :(

Comment: @Sinan: btw, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out this works absolutely fine:

```
def strip_ansi_sequence (str)
  str.gsub(/\e\[[^m]*m/, '')
end
```